# trigonometry sec function not working in PERL

Tags: perl, trigonometry

I have a condition such that

```
cos($x)=$y;
```

Since i know $y, i want to find value of $x

I used

```
$x=sec($y);
```

which gives me error undefined subroutine called.

Please suggest how to fix it. I do not want to use some additional modules.

Comment: I don't know any Perl but you seem to be using a secant function where you should be using the arc cosine function.  The former is the reciprocal of the cosine, the latter the inverse -- there's a big difference.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [perldoc -f cos](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/cos.html)

> *cos*
>
> Returns the cosine of EXPR (expressed in radians). If EXPR is omitted, takes the cosine of $_ .
> For the inverse cosine operation, you may use the Math::Trig::acos() function, or use this relation:

```
sub acos { atan2( sqrt(1 - $_[0] * $_[0]), $_[0] ) }
```